# Vagrant and docker provider

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox

This question has also been posted to the Vagrant Google Group.

My environment:

```
OS-X 10.9.4
VirtualBox 5.012 r104815
Vagrant 1.7.4
```

Trying to use docker provider, with the host machine being geerlingguy/centos7

by placing:

```
config.vm.provision "docker"
```

in host machine vagrant file it auto configures my host machine with the following docker version:

```
Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
API version:  1.20
Package Version: docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
Built:
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
API version:  1.20
Package Version:
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
Built:
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I can run docker containers from hub but when I try to build docker container from Dockerfile I get:

```
Command: "docker" "build" "/var/lib/docker/docker_build_1b35c3f0278e1a3b37d1578d7ce326e5"

Stderr:

Stdout: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in context path: lstat /var/lib/docker/docker_build_1b35c3f0278e1a3b37d1578d7ce326e5: permission denied
```

If I vagrant ssh into centos7 host and run

```
docker build /var/lib/docker/docker_build_1b35c3f0278e1a3b37d1578d7ce326e5
```

I see same error but if I run

```
sudo docker build /var/lib/docker/docker_build_1b35c3f0278e1a3b37d1578d7ce326e5
```

the build runs.

I tried:

```
config.ssh.username = 'root'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

for host machine but then it doesn't find docker command.

Maybe I should add I am doing this in the host vagrantfile:

```
 # Ensure vagrant user can run docker command
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo groupadd docker;true"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo usermod -a -G docker vagrant;true"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker version"
  config.vm.provision :reload
```

and vagrant can run docker.

This is where it falls over (in the docker vagrant file):

```
 config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
     docker.build_dir = /path/to/my/dockerfile/on/the/host/vm (FAILS WITH symlink ERROR)
  end
```

but

```
config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.image = hub/image
end
```

will succeed to create a container.

I have been banging my head for 2 days - reading all sorts about symlink issues in virtualbox and tried all sorts of different settings.

Can anybody advise how I should resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: You reprovisioned the VM after setting the "ensure vagrant user can run docker command" configs right?

Comment: ok, so prior to putting those lines in, the docker vagrantfile would fall over on some docker command. I put the last 'reload' line in (using the reload plugin) and then it seems vagrant can run docker command - indeed it can spin containers from docker hub, just not build due to symlink error, only sudo it seems can build

Comment: I strongly think this is due to the vagrant user needing root access to run docker. Did you [create the docker group, and add the vagrant user to it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)?

Comment: I thought it was clear that I was doing that in  # Ensure vagrant user can run docker command? I dont think its an issue running command per se, but the issue relates to the folder permissions and following sym links.

Comment: I believe this is the issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15037 looks like I need a new docker on my host. How can I script this entirely in Vagrantfile?

Comment: I have upgraded to docker v1.9.1 and unfortunately the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to set sticky bit on /usr/bin/docker.

This allowed docker to follow sym links and complete docker build. Obscure, and not totally sure where the fault lies. I was basically following the recommended workflow for building docker containers with vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix "vagrant" user**:

You may have to go through a [few steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo) to elevate docker's permissions. Otherwise, you can try running `$ sudo docker` instead of just `$ docker`.

**Or fix "root" user:**

If you want to use root instead, it sounds like docker might not be in the root user's path.

`vagrant ssh` into the machine and verify the path for both root & vagrant users:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Then, [add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) the missing docker path to your root user's `$PATH`.

Comment: In case you're not aware, you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark is as the correct answer. That way, this question doesn't remain "unanswered". Unless, you're waiting for someone else to come along and provide input :)

Comment: Done, thanks for the tips, and your time and your input.