# docker build fails to use Dockerfile in **sticky** directory?

Tags: linux, docker, redhat

Running docker 1.12.1; on RH 7.2 64 bit.

docker in general works fine; my commands to run containers; or to import archives ... all fine.

But when I try this here:

```
/data $ docker build -t foo/bar:1 .
```

I get:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /data/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Then I tried:

```
/data $ lstat Dockerfile
bash: lstat: command not found...
Similar command is: 'stat'

/data $ stat Dockerfile
stat: cannot stat ‘Dockerfile’: No such file or directory
```

but

```
/data $ stat /data/Dockefile 
File: ‘/data/Dockefile’
Size: 471           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 127         Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (1125706/guenthne)   Gid: (  600/  gloadl)
Access: 2016-09-05 16:37:42.835090097 +0200
Modify: 2016-09-05 16:37:42.835090097 +0200
Change: 2016-09-05 16:37:42.835090097 +0200
Birth: -
```

And just to be clear: when I use the **same** command; and the **same** dockerfile on my local Ubuntu Linux, all of that works fine. And no, **/data** is not a symbolic link; but I figured: it has the **sticky** bit set. And unfortunately, all directories on that system that I have write permission to (/data, /home, and /tmp) are sticky.

Questions are:

1. Any idea what is causing this problem?
2. Of course, more important: solutions, or at least workarounds?

Update, as requested:

```
> ls -al $(which docker)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13914136 Aug 18 07:07 /bin/docker
```

Comment: you miss the final dot, your command should be `docker build -t aaa .`

Comment: try `strace your command` to see what is going on

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/998

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677042/vagrant-and-docker-provider  ?

Comment: can you post `ls -al $(which docker)` and add the sticky bit if it is not here

Comment: another https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/0VKKZp8RnP8

Comment: About the missing dot: that is just a transcription error; updating my question.

Comment: does the docker image have the sticky bit?

Comment: maybe related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15037

Comment: Thanks everybody for your ideas; but it turned out to be freakin' typo on my side. Just as warning for future docker users; I created an answer and wrote that down (so - setting the sticky bit wasn't necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer to my problem here; just in case somebody accidentally runs into the same problem; as this isn't about  stat, lstat, or anything.

The problem was a simple **typo**: when copying the working Dockerfile to my remote build server; I messed up, and named the file **Dockefile** instead of **Dockerfile** (so the **r** missing within Docke*r*)

In essence, docker gives the correct message:

*unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat **/data/Dockerfile: no such file or directory***

but unfortunately, that prefix about "context/symlinks" is just misleading.